# Pushdown Automata Challenge

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

I read one old-midterm exam on Automata. consider:

[image]

the language that accepted by above pushdown automata is not generated by which of the following grammar?

1) S->aBaa|a$\epsilon$

aB->aS|$\epsilon$

2) S->aaB

aB->aaaB|$\epsilon$

3) S->aaB|a

aB->aaB|$\epsilon$

4) S->aB

B->aaB|$\epsilon$

i think (3) is true, but when we try to solve it with my friends, we think 1 and 3 is true? any hint or idea with detail highly appriciated.

my reasoning is:

(1) and (3) and (4) generates a, but (2) couldent generate a.  PDA Language is {$a^n$ | n is odd}

thanks to all.

Comment: Your "reasoning" is just a list of claims. What is your reasoning for *them*, respectively?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29454/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/911832/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

You identified the language of the PDA correctly.

However, you misidentified the languages generated by the grammars:

Grammar 1 can generate $aa$ via $S \to aBaa$ and $aB \to \epsilon$.

Grammar 2 can generate $a$ via $S \to aaB$ and $aB\to \epsilon$. Also each application of $aB \to aaaB$ inbetween will add exactly 2 $a$'s. So grammar 2 generates the correct language.

Grammar 3 can generate $aa$ via $S\to aaB$, $aB\to aaB$, and $aB\to \epsilon$.

Grammar 4 is equivalent to grammar 2, except every intermediate sentential form is on $a$ shorter.

Comment: Dear FrankW, you means just 2 is correct?

Comment: 2 and 4 generate the language of the PDA, so 1 and 3 are correct answers to the question.